# How to use fragments with skmaps?

Tags: android, android-fragments, skmaps

I'm looking for some really good example to implements skobbler maps on my app. But my app uses a lot of fragments and I want the map be held in a fragment. But there is no guide of how to implement skobbler maps using fragments. There is just the original example from skobbler that use activities.

I know there is **SKMapFragment** but, what's the right way to use it, I don't know. Hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently fragment support is very limited - you can pull it off but you must carefully design your app so that you don't have multiple maps visible on the screen at the same time (transitions also count).

If you have multiple maps in different activities - make sure that you properly set the required flags (documentation [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec033)).

As for the SKMapFragment - [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec005) is the documentation